# scrapy with folder as an input

Tags: python, scrapy

I use scrapy with csv file as input but I want to use a folder with inside some csv file to use as input because my csv is too large to use is directly so I split it in several files.

The beginning on my working script is here :

```
class mySuper(CrawlSpider):
    name="super"
    f = open("/root/super/super/urls.csv")
    allowed_domains = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
    f = open("/root/super/super/urls.csv")
    start_urls = ['http://www.'+url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
    f.close()

    rules = (Rule (LinkExtractor(allow=('(.*)[C-c]ontact','(.*)legal','(.*)mention','(.*)information'),deny=('(.*)='),restrict_xpaths=()), callback="parse_start_url", follow=False),)

    def parse_start_url(self,response):
```

I try this but it only take the last file found in the directory :

```
import os
class mySuper(CrawlSpider):
    name="super"
    directory = os.path.join("c:\\","/root/super/super/csv")
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            f = open("/root/super/super/csv/"+file,'r')
            allowed_domains = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
            f = open("/root/super/super/csv/"+file,'r')
            start_urls = ['http://www.'+url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]

            f.close()

            rules = (Rule (LinkExtractor(allow=('(.*)[C-c]ontact','(.*)legal','(.*)mention','(.*)information'),deny=('(.*)='),restrict_xpaths=()), callback="parse_start_url", follow=False),)

    def parse_start_url(self,response):
```

Thanks for your inputs!

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the variable in loop and that is why the issue is happening. You need to use `append`. Also `allowed_domains` will take the domain name and not the url itself. Below should kind of work for you

```
class mySuper(CrawlSpider):
    name = "super"

    allowed_domains = set()

    rules = (Rule(
        LinkExtractor(allow=('(.*)[C-c]ontact', '(.*)legal', '(.*)mention', '(.*)information'), deny=('(.*)='),
                      restrict_xpaths=()), callback="parse_start_url", follow=False),)

    def start_requests(self):
        directory = os.path.join("c:\\", "/root/super/super/csv")
        from urllib.parse import urlparse

        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
            for file in files:
                f = open("/root/super/super/csv/" + file, 'r')
                for url in f.readlines():
                    domain = urlparse(url).netloc
                    self.allowed_domains.add(domain)
                    yield Request(url)

                f.close()

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks I try but failed : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 127, in _next_request
    request = next(slot.start_requests)
  File "/root/super/super/spiders/mySuper.py", line 74, in start_requests
    self.allowed_domains.append(domain)
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Ahh I changed array to set latter. Change `self.allowed_domains.append(domain) ` to `self.allowed_domains.add(domain)`